# Snapshot of taskscheduler via application

Tags: c#

We use the taskscheduler for a lot of automation tasks.  Rather than create a Excel spreadsheet by hand of all the tasks and details, I have found an API that will allow me to pull the information.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

namespace TaskSchedulerReader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dataSet = ReadData();

        }

        public static async Task<TaskSchedulerSnapshot> ReadData()
        {
            const string localSnapshotPath = @"c:\temp\local_snapshot.zip";

            var cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

            var snapshot = await TaskSchedulerSnapshot.Create(TaskService.Instance.Token, localSnapshotPath,
                cancelToken.Token, new Progress<Tuple<int, string>>());

            return snapshot;

        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the zip file is never created but I am not sure what I am missing?  Once I get the zip file and know how to pull the item details out and finish the application.  Just need to know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote your code, it doesn't wait for `ReadData` to finish. You need to do something like this to wait for thread to finish executing before the `Main` method finishes.

```cs
var dataSet = ReadData().Result;
```

Comment: Ok that got me a bit closer .. now I get an error message "A required privilege is not held by the client."  The file did get created though.

Comment: That's a separate problem. The account you are running the process under doesn't have admin rights. If you are doing this from Visual Studio right now, you need to run VS as an admin.

Comment: Ran VS as admin and still have this issue.  Could it be the token is no good?

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting and what library are you using to interact with the task scheduler?

Comment: 4.5.2 and Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler

Comment: Where does `TaskSchedulerSnapshot` come from?

Comment: Its part of the class Microsoft.win32.TaskScheduler

Comment: I am following the example from here - https://github.com/dahall/TaskScheduler/wiki/Snapshots-and-Multi-threading - without the part of coping it to another machine